Exception in WorkerManager Jetpack
Many exceptions have been raised in FB Crashlytics with stack trace:

Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException no such
table: SystemIdInfo (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT
DISTINCT work_spec_id FROM SystemIdInfo
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement
(SQLiteConnection.java)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement
(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare
(SQLiteConnection.java:652)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare (SQLiteSession.java:590)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram. (SQLiteProgram.java:61)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery. (SQLiteQuery.java:37)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query
(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory
(SQLiteDatabase.java:1545)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory
(SQLiteDatabase.java:1520)
androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.query
(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:161) androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query
(RoomDatabase.java:328) androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query
(DBUtil.java:83)
androidx.work.impl.model.SystemIdInfoDao_Impl.getWorkSpecIds
(SystemIdInfoDao_Impl.java:121)
androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobScheduler.reconcileJobs
(SystemJobScheduler.java:298)
androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.cleanUp
(ForceStopRunnable.java:249)
androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.forceStopRunnable
(ForceStopRunnable.java:215)
androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run
(ForceStopRunnable.java:110)
androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run
(SerialExecutor.java:91)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)

It doesn't relate to my code. My code doesn't use SQLite too.
I also view the code of androidx:work and found that the exception is related to cleanUp() method in ForceStopRunnable class. But it doesn't shed me any light.
Please kindly help me. Thanks
